# How to fix all AMP error like " The tag 'xx' is disallowed." using a script?

Tags: html, amp-html

I have a Java Controller and an Apache Velocity file with a variable in which I have the html to show.

For AMP I have some errors of this type:

The tag '' is disallowed.

I start to do a replace like that:

```
ampParsedBody = ampParsedBody.replaceAll("<iframe ", "<amp-iframe ");
ampParsedBody = ampParsedBody.replaceAll("</iframe>", "</amp-iframe>");
```

But there are a smarter way?
For example a script or at least a list of all the tag I should replace.

In order to avoid to fix one by one and loose too much time.

Comment: There is a documentation for [disallowed tag errors using AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/troubleshooting/validation_errors#disallowed-tag). Tags are whitelisted, so there is no definitive list of all disallowed tags; however, the [AMP specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/spec) broadly defines the set of disallowed tags.

Comment: Thanks Jess, I already read that links just I hoped for a script/tool to fix all. But I think don't exist. It will mean I will solve them slowly one by one.